# Org Wide setting for Community User to edit record

Tags: community, partner-communities, org-wide-defaults

I have created a community. Cloned a Profile with license "Customer Community Plus". When i login into as an customer I see all the Accounts.

I want to change this. User should see/edit only related account and contact.

Account are created by admin hence owner of record is admin.

I tried to make Account as private in "Sharing Settings" and community user was able to see only related record but was not able to edit the record.

How should i implement this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sharing settings should be set to private. Sounds like you already have that covered. Other things to check are:

- The field accessibility (Setup -> Security Controls -> Field Accessibility -> Account or Setup -> Customize -> Account -> Click field label of field you'd like to check -> Button view field accessibility.)
- The community profile object access settings under setup -> sites -> (click site label of community) -> public access settings -> object settings.
- The user profile object access settings for your community user profile. (Mangage users -> profiles -> object settings)

I might be missing something, but this is a nice start.

Comment: 1) All fields of account are visible.
2) I did not using site.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it should be the Field Accessibility (Setup -> Security Controls -> Field Accessibility -> Account or Setup -> Customize -> Account -> Click field label of field you'd like to check -> Button view field accessibility.) I'll change my answer.

Comment: 1) Some of the fields were hidden for custom profile that i have created. Made them visible (i.e. Editable). But did not help. As my record owner is admin so records are editable to only its owner or a role before him. And community user can not be account owner. So how a community user can edit a record that he does not own

Comment: Hmm not sure what it is then. Do you get any kind of error message when you try to include/edit a field?

Comment: I get following error when community user tries to edit record. You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

Comment: Are you editing a custom field or a standard field?

Comment: I am editing custom as well as standard fields.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the field level settings that are the problem - you also need to enable editing at the object level in the community user profile.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

It's in the profile area you have already been editing, but keep scrolling down until you get to the Standard Object Permissions area. It can be a long way down.

This will give the user the ability to edit records that she/he owns. (once you check the edit box)